# Do different android views have different sensitivities?

Tags: android

I'm building an application now and I'm using the `Button` view and setting the background of the button to my images using selector xml files. But I find that the buttons aren't very sensitive to touch and take a bit of effort to press as they are somewhat small.

My question is do different android view elements have different sensitives? Is there a better view to use that would be more sensitive or usable or even a way to adjust the sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the touch sensitivity is the same for all views.  It is recommended that any touch targets (such as your buttons) be at least 48dp on their shortest edge.  If your buttons are smaller than this, it will probably help to increase them.  Doing this is possible using the `android:minWidth` and `android:minHeight` properties:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/my_button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:text="My Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that you're noticing the delay for the button selection. Android (for better or worse -- I personally find it annoyingly slow) adds a delay between when you press a pressable item and when it reflects that pressed state on the UI. I believe it's mostly for things like ListViews, where you might otherwise see a flicker between when you press an item and then move your finger (e.g. you're intending to make a scrolling gesture, but it first shows the item being pressed).

You could handle settings the state in your onTouch event, and on ACTION_DOWN set your pressed state to true, and to false on ACTION_UP.

Comment: Thanks but I don't actually think that is it because sometimes when I press where the buttons are nothing happens no matter how long I wait. But I appreciate the info